# React JS with Redux does not appear to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am just starting to learn React JS with Redux and have, what I think, is a very easy question to answer.  I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from "redux";

//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//

const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    case 'RESET':
      return { ...state, count: state.count = 0 };
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log("subscribe log:",store.getState())
)


const Counter = ({ value, onIncrement, onDecrement, onReset }) => 
(
    <div>
        <h1>{value}</h1>
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={onReset}>Reset</button>
        <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
    </div>
);

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
     <Counter
        value={ store.getState() }
        onIncrement={ () => store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }) }
        onDecrement={ () => store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT'}) }
        onReset={ ()=> store.dispatch({ type: 'RESET'}) }
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

render()
```

When the code executes, the html is rendered but the value of the state is not displayed within the

tags.  When I click on the + button or the - button, I can see the value of state.count increase and decrease by viewing the console. I had expected the value of state.count to display in the

tags but no value is ever displayed.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I believe you have call render inside store.subscribe callback, since you are not using react-redux, you have to manually rerender

Comment: @AngelSalazar I'm not sure I follow what you are saying.  Render is an arrow function defined as a constant but not within anything else, as far as I know.  I thought that the render would re-render on a change of state.  Since the state changes each time I click on the + or - button, react should automatically re-render.  At least that was my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when using redux
your reducers should have a default case where return the initial state

like

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        count: state.count + 1 
      }
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        count: state.count - 1 
       }
    case 'RESET':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        count: state.count = 0
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

another error is that you're passing an object to your counter component,

```
store.getState() // returns an object
```

you should change that to

```
store.getState().count
```

lastly you are using a funcional component (Counter), this does not have state and does not rerender when your store state changes.

If you want to react to your store changes you have to create a class Component where it subscribes to the store in the componentDidMount lifecycle method and use the setState method to rerender your component.

So in order to show changes you have to call render inside your subscribe function like

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        count: state.count + 1 
      }
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        count: state.count - 1 
       }
    case 'RESET':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        count: state.count = 0
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);



const Counter = (props) => {
  const { value, onIncrement, onDecrement, onReset } = props;
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{value}</h1>
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={onReset}>Reset</button>
        <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter 
      value={store.getState().count}
      onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({ type : 'INCREMENT' })}
      onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({ type : 'DECREMENT' })}
      onReset={() => store.dispatch({ type : 'RESET' })}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
  render();
})
render()
```

an a [demo](https://jsbin.com/citafoqiru/edit?js,output)